# FabricJS Import SVG into canvas not rendering

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, fabricjs

I am experimenting with fabricJS. I'm stuck while importing SVG files into the canvas. I saw examples in fabricjs site and used code suggested in SO answers. The imported image is not rendered in the canvas as shown in the fiddle below.

https://jsfiddle.net/d6p80yuk/

Am I missing anything?

Other code that I have tried

```
var group = [];

fabric.loadSVGFromURL($(this).attr("src"),function(objects,options) {
    var loadedObjects = new fabric.Group(group);
    loadedObjects.set({
        width: 200,
        height: 200
    });
    canvas.centerObject(loadedObjects);
    canvas.add(loadedObjects);
    canvas.renderAll();
},function(item, object) {
    object.set('id',item.getAttribute('id'));
    group.push(object);
});
```

Comment: The issue is only with the ssl. You are trying to load non secure content (svg image from http) over secure page (js fiddle on https). Instead try this link - http://jsfiddle.net/d6p80yuk/

Comment: ranjana can you post this as answer

Comment: I am testing this on my local system in apache port 80, which uses http. I just copy pasted the code.

Answer (score 1):

After a little messing around with the Chrome error log,I found a error message that says mixed request was loaded. If you are using chrome and working on jsfiddle like me, try to use http while loading to jsfiddle. Hope this can help you!

edit: Means to use http to load jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d6p80yuk/

Comment: I am using this code on my local system. AS the example code shows, I'm trying to load image from my local system. It gives me the same result as posted in fiddle. An empty fabric item. I checked the network log in chrome. The xhr request returned the code 200.

Comment: The JSfiddle is to show the code I'm working with. If there is more debugging I have to check please mention that. I can see the http version of jsfiddle works. My local system uses http://localhost/app, but doesn't serve the content from the local machine nor from remote url. I am using laravelPHP 5.3